# Isotope Filtering not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, filter, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to set up a page with an isotope filtering function. 
Here's my code:

```
      $(document).ready(function() {

            var $container = $('#isotope');

            $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
                // init

                $container.isotope({
                    // options
                    itemSelector : '.col-md-4',
                    layoutMode : 'masonry',

                    masonry : {
                        columnWidth : $container.find('.grid-sizer')[0],
                        gutter : 0
                    }

                });
            });

            $(function() {

                // filter functions

                // bind filter button click
                $('a.title').on('click', function() {

                    var filterValue = $(".col-md-4").attr('data-filter');
                    // use filterFn if matches value



                    $container.isotope({
                        filter : filterValue
                    });
                });

            });

        });
```

Filtering works fine in Chrome. In Firefox only the masonry works, not the filter function. I also tried simply filtering by class, this didn't work either. Strangely the Isotope Demo works fine in Firefox...
Thanks for your help. M

Comment: You need to make a jsfiddle or at least post your html.

Answer (score 0):

```
$container.isotope({
  // filter element with numbers greater than 50
  filter: function() {
    // `this` is the item element. Get text of element's .number
    var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
    // return true to show, false to hide
    return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50;
  }
})
```

[See filtering with function here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html#functions)